# Wordpress, how to debug Javascript to check a specific behavior

Tags: javascript, wordpress, debugging, reload

I need to debug Javascript to check which function is called on a specific behavior.

To be more specific, when we click inside an iframe, all the page or at least the iframe is reloaded, so loaded 2 times.

For example, if you take a look at this page:
https://artetcadres.fr/art-et-images/#collection/hopper/

and click on the artist "Klimt", the main page activate a javascript function, display this image on the entire page and reload the iframe content.

I tried with the Chrome Devtools but can't figure out which function is called display the image "Loading..." and reload the iframe.

It's reloaded maybe because the url is dynamically updated. The anchor `#collection/hopper/` will become `#collection/klimt/`.

This strange behavior appeared after an wordpress upgrade.

[image]